# Pdf to Excel through python

Tags: python, excel, pdf

I have a multiple pdf file that i extract the data through python and store it in excel. The text from the pdf are extract correctly to excel but when it comes to table in the pdf, it did not extract as a table but it threated as a normal text. Is there any method that can i extract/copy the table from the excel and store it in the excel through python?

[Some of the table inside the pdf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdjZf.png)

Comment: PDF has no tables. PDF isn't a data format, it's a file containing print instructions. What looks like a table is lines between specific page coordinates and raw text. `treated as a normal text.` because that's what it is. Libraries like `tabulaPy` try to *guess* table layouts and contents but can easily fail, especially when there are no vertical lines to separate columns

Comment: i try to use tabulaPY but its not working

Comment: "It's not working".  What isn't working?  Does it generate a bad Excel file?  Does it output gibberish in Excel?  Does it generate the wrong format?   All of that(and more) constitutes as 'not working'.    Which is it?

Comment: it came out error '(C:\Users\Me\PycharmProjects\Pdf Extract Data\venv\lib\site-packages\tabula\__init__.py)

Comment: @khkyt add a minimal working example